# Unable to upload image to the server it show zero byte?

Tags: android

When I'm taking an image from gallery and want to insert into server, it puts the image with zero byte size. And in the table I have two columns, `rollno` and `image`. I get the `rollno` value from shared preference but it does not put the  `rollno` in the database table, `rollno` column shows empty.

Help me to resolve this.

Here is my code

```
public class ImageEditActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView image;
    Button btn_cancel_edit,btn_done_edit;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    String rollno;

    String KEY_Rollno = "rollno";
    String KEY_IMAGE = "image";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_edit);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        bitmap=ProfileActivity.bitmap;
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




        btn_done_edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_done_edit);
        btn_cancel_edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_edit);

        btn_done_edit.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_cancel_edit.setOnClickListener(this);

        sp=getSharedPreferences("rajput",MODE_PRIVATE);
        rollno=sp.getString("rollno",null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == btn_done_edit){
            uploadImage();
        }
        if(v == btn_cancel_edit){
              onBackPressed();

        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage() {

        String UPLOAD_URL ="http://aptronnoida.com/applock/image_insert.php";

        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Disimissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast message of the response
                        Toast.makeText(ImageEditActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Showing toast
                        Toast.makeText(ImageEditActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_Rollno,rollno);
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);


                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void onBackPressed(){

        super.finish();
    }


}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a `GET` to upload the image, which is probably a bad idea. Depending on your version of PHP, you might be limited to as little at 512 chars for the whole request, which is about an image of 3KB when bast64 encoded. Try to use a POST instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below working code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;

    private ImageView imageView;

    private EditText editTextName;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private String UPLOAD_URL = "http://coderzheaven.com/sample_file_upload/upload_image.php";

    private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private String KEY_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);

        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Disimissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast message of the response
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Showing toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

                //Getting Image Name
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
                params.put("Roll_NO", "5");

                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            showFileChooser();
        }

        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Reference source: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to PNG and reduce the compression in the following line

```
 bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

To

```
 bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, baos);
```